# Problemas ao fechar menu ao clicar em links

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle, ancora

Pessoal fiz um site `onepage` está nesse [link](http://agenciafront.com.br/oburguer/), ele tem um menu fixo na lateral que abre quando é clicado porem é o seguinte nesses links existem ancoras que quando são clicadas o site desce normalmente porém o menu não fecha ao clicar no link a ideia é que feche segue parte do meu código vocês podem ver o problema acessando o link.

JS do toggle:

```
class ShapeOverlays {
    constructor(elm) {
        this.elm = elm;
        this.path = elm.querySelectorAll('path');
        this.numPoints = 2;
        this.duration = 600;
        this.delayPointsArray = [];
        this.delayPointsMax = 0;
        this.delayPerPath = 200;
        this.timeStart = Date.now();
        this.isOpened = false;
        this.isAnimating = false;
    }
    toggle() {
        this.isAnimating = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
            this.delayPointsArray[i] = 0;
        }
        if (this.isOpened === false) {
            this.open();
        } else {
            this.close();
        }
    }
    open() {
        this.isOpened = true;
        this.elm.classList.add('is-opened');
        this.timeStart = Date.now();
        this.renderLoop();
    }
    close() {
        this.isOpened = false;
        this.elm.classList.remove('is-opened');
        this.timeStart = Date.now();
        this.renderLoop();
    }
    updatePath(time) {
        const points = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
            const thisEase = this.isOpened ?
                    (i == 1) ? ease.cubicOut : ease.cubicInOut :
                    (i == 1) ? ease.cubicInOut : ease.cubicOut;
            points[i] = thisEase(Math.min(Math.max(time - this.delayPointsArray[i], 0) / this.duration, 1)) * 100
        }

        let str = '';
        str += (this.isOpened) ? `M 0 0 V ${points[0]} ` : `M 0 ${points[0]} `;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints - 1; i++) {
            const p = (i + 1) / (this.numPoints - 1) * 100;
            const cp = p - (1 / (this.numPoints - 1) * 100) / 2;
            str += `C ${cp} ${points[i]} ${cp} ${points[i + 1]} ${p} ${points[i + 1]} `;
        }
        str += (this.isOpened) ? `V 0 H 0` : `V 100 H 0`;
        return str;
    }
    render() {
        if (this.isOpened) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
                this.path[i].setAttribute('d', this.updatePath(Date.now() - (this.timeStart + this.delayPerPath * i)));
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
                this.path[i].setAttribute('d', this.updatePath(Date.now() - (this.timeStart + this.delayPerPath * (this.path.length - i - 1))));
            }
        }
    }
    renderLoop() {
        this.render();
        if (Date.now() - this.timeStart < this.duration + this.delayPerPath * (this.path.length - 1) + this.delayPointsMax) {
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                this.renderLoop();
            });
        } else {
            this.isAnimating = false;
        }
    }
}

(function () {
    const elmHamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
    const gNavItems = document.querySelectorAll('.global-menu__item');
    const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
    const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

    elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (overlay.isAnimating) {
            return false;
        }
        overlay.toggle();
        if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
            elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi');
            for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
                gNavItems[i].classList.add('is-opened');
            }
        } else {
            elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
            for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
                gNavItems[i].classList.remove('is-opened');
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

Comment: Estou postando a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com este código você consegue criar um *listener* para cada link do menu, que irá fechar o menu ao ser clicado:

```
for(x=0;x<gNavItems.length;x++){
  gNavItems[x].addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (overlay.isAnimating) {
      return false;
    }
    overlay.toggle();
    if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
      elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi');
      for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
        gNavItems[i].classList.add('is-opened');
      }
    } else {
      elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
      for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
        gNavItems[i].classList.remove('is-opened');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Onde colocar?**

No arquivo `menu-fixed-svg.js` (código completo abaixo):

```
class ShapeOverlays {
  constructor(elm) {
    this.elm = elm;
    this.path = elm.querySelectorAll('path');
    this.numPoints = 2;
    this.duration = 600;
    this.delayPointsArray = [];
    this.delayPointsMax = 0;
    this.delayPerPath = 200;
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.isAnimating = false;
  }
  toggle() {
    this.isAnimating = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
      this.delayPointsArray[i] = 0;
    }
    if (this.isOpened === false) {
      this.open();
    } else {
      this.close();
    }
  }
  open() {
    this.isOpened = true;
    this.elm.classList.add('is-opened');
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.renderLoop();
  }
  close() {
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.elm.classList.remove('is-opened');
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.renderLoop();
  }
  updatePath(time) {
    const points = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
      const thisEase = this.isOpened ? 
                        (i == 1) ? ease.cubicOut : ease.cubicInOut:
                        (i == 1) ? ease.cubicInOut : ease.cubicOut;
      points[i] = thisEase(Math.min(Math.max(time - this.delayPointsArray[i], 0) / this.duration, 1)) * 100
    }

    let str = '';
    str += (this.isOpened) ? `M 0 0 V ${points[0]} ` : `M 0 ${points[0]} `;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints - 1; i++) {
      const p = (i + 1) / (this.numPoints - 1) * 100;
      const cp = p - (1 / (this.numPoints - 1) * 100) / 2;
      str += `C ${cp} ${points[i]} ${cp} ${points[i + 1]} ${p} ${points[i + 1]} `;
    }
    str += (this.isOpened) ? `V 0 H 0` : `V 100 H 0`;
    return str;
  }
  render() {
    if (this.isOpened) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
        this.path[i].setAttribute('d', this.updatePath(Date.now() - (this.timeStart + this.delayPerPath * i)));
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
        this.path[i].setAttribute('d', this.updatePath(Date.now() - (this.timeStart + this.delayPerPath * (this.path.length - i - 1))));
      }
    }
  }
  renderLoop() {
    this.render();
    if (Date.now() - this.timeStart < this.duration + this.delayPerPath * (this.path.length - 1) + this.delayPointsMax) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.renderLoop();
      });
    }
    else {
      this.isAnimating = false;
    }
  }
}

(function() {
  const elmHamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
  const gNavItems = document.querySelectorAll('.global-menu__item');
  const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
  const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

    for(x=0;x<gNavItems.length;x++){
      gNavItems[x].addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (overlay.isAnimating) {
          return false;
        }
        overlay.toggle();
        if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
          elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi');
          for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
            gNavItems[i].classList.add('is-opened');
          }
        } else {
          elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
          for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
            gNavItems[i].classList.remove('is-opened');
          }
        }
      });
    }

  elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (overlay.isAnimating) {
      return false;
    }
    overlay.toggle();
    if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
      elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi');
      for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
        gNavItems[i].classList.add('is-opened');
      }
    } else {
      elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
      for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
        gNavItems[i].classList.remove('is-opened');
      }
    }
  });
}());
```

Comment: animal cara manja muito vlw

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma função onclick="" nos links que ao serem clicados fechariam o menu.

Comment: deixa eu ver se entendi eu crio a função onclick no menu e chamo oque ? na função que mandei acima tem uma parada pra fechar só que não fecha não sei se chegou a ver

toggle() {
        this.isAnimating = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
            this.delayPointsArray[i] = 0;
        }
        if (this.isOpened === false) {
            this.open();
        } else {
            this.close();
        }
    }

Answer (score -1):

No teu app.js descomenta a função que começa na linha 25 e vai até a linha 39. Abaixo segue a função:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".link-menu-side").on("click", function(e) {
        $(".hamburger").addClass("is-opened-navi");
        $(".shape-overlays").addClass("is-opened");
        e.stopPropagation()
    });
    $(document).on("click", function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is(".hamburger") === false) {
            $(".hamburger").removeClass("is-opened-navi");
        }
        if ($(e.target).is(".shape-overlays") === false) {
            $(".shape-overlays").removeClass("is-opened");
        }
    });
});
```